# ADB over wifi with laptop connected to router through cable works but not through WiFi

Tags: android, wifi, adb, ping

So I recently started to learn android development with Android Studio and I want to connect my phone through ADB over wifi.

ADB connects without any problems when my laptop is directly connected to router with cable but it doesn't work when laptop is on wifi. Pinging both phone and laptop from router works, pinging phone from laptop while connected through cable works as well but not through wifi, it returns "Request timed out".

I assume that problem is in laptop wifi adapter or router which probably doesn't allow wifi clients to communicate.

Phone is Galaxy S2 with CM11, laptop HP ProBook 4540s and router is AirLive WN-200R.

Comment: I already tried to switch the firewall off.

Comment: Uncheck the `Isolation Between SSID`checkbox on your router's `Wireless` settings page

Comment: This worked,  thank you. The option was `Isolation within SSID` though.